# How to give custom name to executable file formed by compiling CSharp code at command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, c#, command-line-arguments

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. I have created a project `HelloCSharp`. My project location is:

`C:\Users\Sonevol\source\repos\HelloCSharp`

I go to `HelloCSharp` folder in which I have `Program.cs` file

Then I write in command prompt

```
csc Program.cs
```

which gives me the new file `Program.exe`

Now I want that instead of `Program.exe` my newly generated file will be named as `MyProgram.exe`

How to achieve so?

Comment: An obvious question: why don't you call your source `MyProgram.cs`?

Comment: I mean as in linux there is the option called `-o`, is there any such option in Windows?

Comment: find more details for csc command line at below location https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `/out:` does what you want:

```
csc /out:MyProgram.exe Program.cs
```

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) for more information on the `csc` run string.